# How can I move files from an intermediate folder to an enclosing outer folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a folder called 'outer-folder/intermediate-folder/' that contains multiple contents. How do I remove the `intermediate-folder/`, moving all the contents into the parent `outer-folder/`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one "low-tech" way to do this: in the explorer pane, open the intermediate folder to view its contents, select them all by clicking the first one, then clicking the last one while holding <kbd>shift</kbd>, then click and drag them all to go under the outer folder. Then click the now-empty `intermediate-folder/` and press <kbd>delete</kbd>.

You could also do this via command line using the `mv` command (or `Move-Item` on PowerShell).